Finding percent cover of a raster image
I Have a raster layer in QGIS - The raster symbology represents 5 classes ranging from <0.2% to 0.9%. These classes represent vegetation densities. I would like to know what percent of each class range is present. I have attached photos of my raster classes. Raster Info. My raster does not have an attribute table. Please help!
I have tried creating an intersect polygon and then a dissolved polygon however, the dissolved polygon does not show the same classes or areas as my raster polygon. The data set is to large to use a histogram to extract pixel values and then use excel to find the percent's of each pixel count.

You could save the raster as a rendered image i.e. you would have up to 5 unique values in the output raster. Then run the processing tool Raster layer unique values report which will give output like this:

